# Counting column times number ordered in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

we are working with a table that has a column for every SKU ordered by a customer. So if a particular SKU has been ordered by five different customers, it will appear 5 times. Also, some customers may order 2 of that SKU so in the 'number_ordered' column next to it, there will be a 2. I'm not so good at drawing this out in words so I'll give an example of what the database looks like.

```
+------------+-----------------+
| item_SKU   |  Number Ordered |
+------------+-----------------+
| SKU001     |  3              |
| SKU001     |  2              |
| SKU002     |  15             |
| SKU003     |  1              |
+------------+-----------------+
```

How can I times the sku by the number ordered and then add them all together in MySQL. I need to put it into PHP but I can do that if i get some hints on how to do this.

Cheers

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ? question is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the total ordered item of same `item_SKU` and use it in `PHP`. If you need the order count also, use `COUNT()` function

```
SELECT item_SKU, SUM(Number_Ordered) as Total_Ordered_Item, COUNT(Number_Ordered) as Total_Order_Count
FROM table
GROUP BY item_SKU
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using count' with group by sku name (SKU001). it returns an output with the count of different sku's.

Answer (score 0):

try below `SQL` query

**1.Sum of Orders**

```
select item_SKU,sum(number_ordered) as orders from `table Name` group by item_SKU order by item_SKU
```

**output**

```
item_SKU  | Number Ordered
SKU001    | 5
SKU002    | 15
SKU003    | 1
```

**2. Query** to count no of orders

```
select item_SKU,count(number_ordered) as orders from `table Name` group by item_SKU order by item_SKU
```

**output**

```
item_SKU  | Number Ordered
SKU001    | 2
SKU002    | 1
SKU003    | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT item_SKU,
COUNT(item_SKU) CNT,SUM(Number_Ordered) TOTAL 
FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY item_SKU;
```

### [SQL Fiddles](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ec2b9/3)

Answer (score 0):

Select item_SKU, SUM(NumberOrdered) As total from [table name] group by item_SKU

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It gives you total no of occurrence as 'COUNT' and sum of number_ordered as 'SUM_NUM_ORDER'

```
SELECT item_SKU,COUNT(item_SKU) as COUNT,SUM(Number_Ordered) as SUM_NUM_ORDER FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY item_SKU;
```

DEMO:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ec2b9/10